# Can i render an image from a URI in a FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Right now in my react-native app, i can require a local images, and thumbnails appear nicely arranged in my grid.

```
render() {
      return (

         <View style={styles.grid}>
            <FlatList    
              data={[
                require("./app_thumbnails/p03zbzlm.jpg"),
                require("./app_thumbnails/jwc-small.jpg"),
                require("./app_thumbnails/digital-music.jpg")
              ]}

          />
         </View>
      );
 }
```

How can i use a uri (for example: 
 "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/42.jpg" ) instead of the require() as my data?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, though you may need to tweak the style etc for the [`Image`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image)

```
render() {
    return (
       <View style={styles.grid}>
         <FlatList    
           data={[{uri:'html://image.source.one/image.png'}, 
                 {uri:'html://image.source.two/image2.png'},
                 {uri:'html://image.source.three/image3.png'}
            ]}
            renderItem={({item})=><Image source={{uri: item.uri}}}
      />
     </View>
  );
}
```